# I can not run an Angular2 app hosted with a Node.js/Express in cloud 9

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I am probably missing something in here but it already took me 3 days trying to fix that...any idea will be a big help!
Angular 2 is running in the port 8081 and node.js express in port 8080 but I can not call my index.HTML in the 8080 and get the angular 2. I watched many videos people installing express then cloning angular 2, after that they are able to copy index.HTLM code under "src/app/" and pasting in index.HTML in "views" folder, then starts the node.js server they can get angular. 
You can follow the step by step installation process below...

**1. Created the "blank" workspace in the cloud 9**

**1.1 Updated enviroment in cloud 9**

```
Get the latest node.js
$ nvm install node
$ nvm use 7.5.0
$ nvm alias default v7.5.0
Update npm.
$ npm install -g npm
```

**2. Installed Express globally**

```
$ npm install -g express-generator
Create the app:
$ express --view=ejs -f .
Install dependencies:
$ npm install
```

**3.Then install the Angular-CLI globally**

```
$ npm install -g angular/cli
$ ng new client
$ cd client
$ ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8081 --live-reload-port 8080
```

**Folders structure:**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/11UuQ.png)

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/client/views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

app.listen(process.env.PORT, function () {
console.log('Start server in port: ' + process.env.PORT);
});

module.exports = app;
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('index.html');
});

module.exports = router;
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Angular QuickStart</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.import('main.js').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app>Loading AppComponent content here ...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

**app.component.ts**
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>`,
})
export class AppComponent  { name = 'Angular'; }
```

With 2 servers up and running...

**Port: 8080** and **Port: 8081**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlJq6.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use angular cli to build angular 2 project then ng build -- prod  to build for production of your angular 2 project. The copy the contents of build folder and paste into node server views folder. And change your node server view engine configuration.  Then start the node server not angular server.

- Update angular cli

Comment: When I run the command ng build --prod then created the folder "dist" and I copied the content to inside of "views" folder in node. I just changed one line in "app.js" `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'views')));`, when I started the node server by $ node app and I got the angular first page "app works!". Thank you very much! You saved me a lot of time...

Comment: Welcome, :) I think you can accept it as an answer.

Comment: Sorry, I gave you but it didn't really increase because I have a recent login and I need to increase my reputation in order to count my rate.